# Is there YouTube Live Broadcast via API Thing

Tags: php, api, youtube

I need to know about a feature of YouTube live broadcasting. I am even not familiar whether this feature is in YouTube or not. If it is then is there a API that allows to interface with that?

Answer (score 1):

YouTube Live Broadcasting is currently under beta-tested by a few selected companies. So there is probably no public documentation available.

Comment: This is true, the first test was launched on 13th of this month.